# Passing data between views not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, segue

I know this question was asked about a 100 times but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This ist my second iOS App. I want to modify a Label in my ViewControllerB by pressing a Button in my ViewControllerA.

1. I made a Segue in Storyboard from my Button (`ViewControllerA`) to my `ViewControllerB` and called it "TestSegue".
2. Wrote `#import "ViewControllerB.h` in my `ViewControllerA.h`
3. I wrote this Code in my ViewControllerA.m :

`-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{`

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TestSegue"]){

ViewControllerB *controller = (ViewControllerB *)segue.destinationViewController;
controller.TestLabel.text = @"TEST!";}}
```

In my ViewControllerB nothing happens with the TestLabel...

Can anybody see what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Works now thanks to rpledge.

New Code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TestSegue"]){

ViewControllerB *controller = (ViewControllerB *)segue.destinationViewController;
controller.TestString = @"TEST!";}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'l likely because the TextLabel UI element isn't created until viewDidLoad is run, which will happen after prepareForSegue:

I don't like exposing UI elements for views publicly anyway, I would suggest you add an @property for your NSString* to the destination view controller then set the UILabel.text in viewDidLoad:

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign it to the control, but to an instance variable.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *var;
```

And then in the viewDidLoad assign this to the control.